# How to change a nested value in a dictionary as an upper level key

Tags: javascript, json, dictionary

I have a json file in a specific format, but i want to change it to the format in which i require to pick up one of the nested values, and project them as upper level keys

I tried the suggestion from stackoverflow only, and tired to reach to the specific nested value , but I am not able to lift it up.

```
data = open('sampleDemo.json','r')
json_decode=json.load(data)
for item in data:
    mydict={}
    mydict['spk1'] = item.get('audioResponse').get('startTime').get('emotion').get.....
    print mydict
```

desired output:

[image]

Input file looks like this:

```
{
   "audioResponse": [

  {
     "speaker":"spk1",
     "startTime": "0.0",
     "endTime": "15.239",
     "emotion": "neutral",
     "emotionScore": "0"
  },

  {
     "speaker":"silence",
     "startTime": "15.240",
     "endTime": "16.900",
     "emotion": "NA",
     "emotionScore": "NA"
  },

  {
     "speaker":"spk2",
     "startTime": "16.932",
     "endTime": "27.320",
     "emotion": "happy",
     "emotionScore": "2"
  },

  {
     "speaker":"spk1",
     "startTime": "27.977",
     "endTime": "37.900",
     "emotion": "anger",
     "emotionScore": "-3"
  } 
]}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
var data = {
  "audioResponse": [{
      "speaker": "spk1",
      "startTime": "0.0",
      "endTime": "15.239",
      "emotion": "neutral",
      "emotionScore": "0"
    }, {
      "speaker": "silence",
      "startTime": "15.240",
      "endTime": "16.900",
      "emotion": "NA",
      "emotionScore": "NA"
    }, {
      "speaker": "spk2",
      "startTime": "16.932",
      "endTime": "27.320",
      "emotion": "happy",
      "emotionScore": "2"
    }, {
      "speaker": "spk1",
      "startTime": "27.977",
      "endTime": "37.900",
      "emotion": "anger",
      "emotionScore": "-3"
    }]
};

var result = {
  audioResponse: []
};

for (var item of data.audioResponse) {
  var existed = result.audioResponse.find(x => x[item.speaker]);
  if (!existed)
    result.audioResponse.push({
      [item.speaker]: []
    });

  existedArray = result.audioResponse.find(x => x[item.speaker])[item.speaker];

  var copy = {...item};
  delete copy.speaker;
  existedArray.push(copy);
}

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var inputList = {
   "audioResponse": [

  {
     "speaker":"spk1",
     "startTime": "0.0",
     "endTime": "15.239",
     "emotion": "neutral",
     "emotionScore": "0"
  },

  {
     "speaker":"silence",
     "startTime": "15.240",
     "endTime": "16.900",
     "emotion": "NA",
     "emotionScore": "NA"
  },

  {
     "speaker":"spk2",
     "startTime": "16.932",
     "endTime": "27.320",
     "emotion": "happy",
     "emotionScore": "2"
  },

  {
     "speaker":"spk1",
     "startTime": "27.977",
     "endTime": "37.900",
     "emotion": "anger",
     "emotionScore": "-3"
  } 
]}




var result = inputList.audioResponse.reduce((acc, {speaker, ...rest})=>{
    acc['audioResponse'][speaker] = (acc['audioResponse'][speaker]) || [];
    acc['audioResponse'][speaker].push(rest);
    return acc;
}, {audioResponse:{}});

console.log(result);
```

you can use [reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) method. Hope it helps you !

Answer (score 0):

> but i want to change it to the format in which i require to pick up one of the nested values, and project them as upper level keys

You can set the attribute for the group formation to be dynamic

```
'use strict';

let attribute = 'speaker'; // can be 'speaker' or 'emotion' or 'emotionScore'
let output = {
  audioResponse: []
};

for (let response of data.audioResponse) {
  let groupKey = response[attribute];
  let group = output.audioResponse[groupKey];
  delete response[attribute]; //remove the key
  if (group) {
    group.push(response);
  } else {
    group = [response];
  }
  output.audioResponse[groupKey] = group;
}

console.log(output);
```